# How to integrate an existing neo4j database via neomodel in django?

Tags: python, django-models, neo4j, neomodel, inspectdb

I'm relatively new to neo4j and want to integrate an **existing** database in django for python with neomodel (django-neomodel).

Can the corresponding node models be derived from the existing neo4j database? Like inspectdb for relational databases in django..

If not, I'm able to write the models myself. Do I need to execute the neomodel_install_labels command afterwards? Because the labels are already there..

Thank you!
Max

Comment: Saw that you'd also posted this on the Neomodel Github - from the lack of response there, and the answer to https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/django-neomodel/issues/11, it looks like there's no equivalent of inspectdb for Neomodel.